# Call to a member function where() on array php

Tags: php, nette

```
        $customers = \dibi::select('*')->from('accounts')->fetchAll();
    if($username){
        $customers = $customers->where("username", $username);
    }
```

I have got problem with this code. Error is:

> Call to a member function where() on array.

Comment: What framework?

Comment: If you're trying to add the username to the query, then you have to do that before you fetchAll().

Comment: Nette framework and dibi :)

Comment: `fetchAll()` returns an array of all the results, not an object. You can't use methods of your class to filter it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fetchAll` return `ISelection`. You dont call Where on ISelection

```
if($username){
  $customers = \dibi::select('*')->from('accounts')->where("username", $username)->fetchAll();
}
```

or

```
$customersTable = \dibi::select('*')->from('accounts');

if($username){
  $customersTable = \dibi::select('*')->from('accounts')->where("username", $username);
}

$customers = $customersTable->fetchAll();
```